# Usage of a and an before the letter o

Tags: articles

Why do we use an before old lady and a before a one  eyed giant?

Comment: It is a question of pronounciation rather than orthography. - one" and "unit" for instance,  begin with vowels, but the initial sounds are those of the consonants "w" and "y" as in "won" and "you" therefore  you say : a unit or a one time thing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with pronunciation.  The word “one” is pronounced such that it seems to start with a “w”.  Another common example is “a unicorn”, where “unicorn” is pronounced as if there is a “y” in front.  The phrase “an hour”, on the other hand, sounds like “our”, which is a vowel.  Hence it is “an”.